# Write tests to enforce invariants on AWS infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So in my day to day work I came across this problem. I am new to the whole Infrastructure as code thingy and am using Terraform to deploy our infrastructure. So it has been a up and down ride for me. I enjoy using terraform but recently came across a situation that I wanted to guard against and am looking for a way to solve.
I am using AWS exclusively.

So , I had a SNS topic with a policy created to filter out which queues are able to get what kind of messages. So a subscription filter policy is created on to filter out some messages depending on their JSON contents.
Now during this work I did some copy paste error and the policy was not created correctly. However because there is no way I know ti write tests and sort of guard against it the code checked in and was not working as expected.

Considering we are a CI/CD team and every code push results in a live publish this can be a costly mistake. So I was looking for how to write tests to guard against it.

Tools I am using are Terraform on AWS.

Comment: Great question. Its software  so you you can test for anyting in a CI CD build pipeline. Is this more of a syntax checker or an actual SMS notification test?

Comment: i am imagining a test that could check(in this case) the subscription policy for a particular queue. If that fails the pipeline can turn red nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The Open Policy Agent may be what you're looking for: [OPA with Terraform](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/terraform/).  In the example OPA Policy, they demonstrate how you could unauthorize plans that make changes to IAM resources.

Comment: Thanks i will take a look into this. It looks like a lot of reading though. Just to make sure what I am imagining is a test that could check(in this case) the subscription policy for a particular queue. If that fails the pipeline can turn red nicely. Can that be easily done with OPA ?